# pip3 install pandas failing in gitlab-ci.yaml

Tags: python, pandas, gitlab-ci

pip3 install pandas failing in gitlab-ci.yaml

It is failing as shown below, pasting logs.
I am getting this error once I run my yaml file, for rest of the pip install it is working fine. It is failing only for Pandas.

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

I have left it like this for hours, with no progress, what is wrong?

Without success, I have tried:

Pip Install hangs

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174186

````
$ pip3 install pymysql
Collecting pymysql
  Downloading PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 43.8/43.8 KB 7.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pymysql
Successfully installed pymysql-1.0.2
$ pip uninstall numpy
WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed.
$ pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.4.1.tar.gz (4.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.9/4.9 MB 52.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [308 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
        Using cached setuptools-60.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10
        Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.1.30-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.19.3
        Downloading numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 73.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [276 lines of output]
            Running from numpy source directory.
            setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
              run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
            Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
            blas_opt_info:
            blas_mkl_info:
            customize UnixCCompiler
              libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            blis_info:
              libraries blis not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            openblas_info:
              libraries openblas not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
            Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
              libraries tatlas not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_3_10_blas_info:
              libraries satlas not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_blas_threads_info:
            Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
              libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
    
            flame_info:
              libraries flame not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_3_10_threads_info:
            Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
              libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
            <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_3_10_info:
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries satlas,satlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
              libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
            <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_threads_info:
            Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
              libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
            <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            atlas_info:
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
              libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
              libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
            <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            lapack_info:
              libraries lapack not found in ['/builds/gp-cpg-iot/datawarehouse/data-pipelines/kolo-device-dimension-qr-update/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            /tmp/pip-install-vaexwiws/numpy_677c648f418b4b9ba0617c24747fe32e/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
                Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
                the LAPACK environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
            lapack_src_info:
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            /tmp/pip-install-vaexwiws/numpy_677c648f418b4b9ba0617c24747fe32e/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
                Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
                Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
                numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
                the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
              return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
              FOUND:
                language = c
                define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
      
            /tmp/pip-build-env-mvp8ezwv/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
              warnings.warn(msg)
            running dist_info
            running build_src
            build_src
            building py_modules sources
            creating build
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
            building library "npymath" sources
            Could not locate executable gfortran
            Could not locate executable f95
            Could not locate executable ifort
            Could not locate executable ifc
            Could not locate executable lf95
            Could not locate executable pgfortran
            Could not locate executable nvfortran
            Could not locate executable f90
            Could not locate executable f77
            Could not locate executable fort
            Could not locate executable efort
            Could not locate executable efc
            Could not locate executable g77
            Could not locate executable g95
            Could not locate executable pathf95
            Could not locate executable nagfor
            don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
            None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
            building library "npysort" sources
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
              adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
            None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
            building library "npyrandom" sources
            building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
            creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray
            conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
            building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/tmp/tmp1gke7ac6_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/tmp/tmp1gke7ac6_in_process.py", line 345, in main
       
                raise SystemError(
            SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed
      
      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1```
````